# PHP: Passing a class instance to another page?

Tags: php, class, forms, post, captcha

I'm trying to implement a captcha system, and I found a nice and very simple class trough google that does what I want.

it's something like:

```
$captcha = new Captcha();
$prefix = mt_rand();
$image = $captcha->generate($prefix);
```

then I add the image in the form:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<input name="captcha" type="text" value="Type the security code from above" />
```

it works fine so far, but I don't know how to check if the submitted code matches the captcha.
In the documentation, it says I have to do it with:

```
$correct = $captcha_instance->check($prefix, $_POST['captcha']);
```

but the problem is that after the form is submitted `$captcha` and `$prefix` are gone...

How do I pass these variables after the form is submitted to the next page?

Comment: You need to show a link to said captcha class. -- But try to just instantiate a new one. The ->check method might work independently. (Else you will have to serialize the original object into $_SESSION.)

Comment: @mario: you were right :D it's only the $prefix I needed to pass as a hidden input field :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @mario: you were right :D it's only
>   the $prefix I needed to pass as a
>   hidden input field :)

That's a very bad idea - in your form tag, if say you have hidden field `captcha_answer` and you're passing the value of that to `$captchaInstance->check()`, then you defeat the purpose of a captcha. Captcha's are to sort out robots from humans, but its so simple to read a value by downloading the source in the captcha solving bot and just getting the `value="{answer}"` out of the source.

Instead, you should use this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['answer'] = $prefix;
?>
```

Then in your checker you do this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$prefix = $_SESSION['answer'];
$passed = $captcha->check($prefix);
?>
```

In fact, I think this class would be better as only having static methods, but that's my opinion. Anyway, this way means that all the data is only stored server-side so they can't just view source for captcha answer.

Comment: but $prefix is not the captcha code. I think it is its ID or something, because I see a php and a image filename generated with this ID. the php file has the captcha code in it inside a variable.

Comment: That's a bit better than just putting the captcha code in the source, but still vulnerable as a spammer could just download that library and copy/paste the algorithm to generate the captcha answer from `$prefix` in their bot and then have the bot respond with the return value of that algorithm.

Comment: Indeed, but that is no reason to allow spammers to use your captcha protected form very easily. As soon as one find your site, you'll be drowning in database entries (or emails) from form submissions.

Comment: What happens if the the contact form gets instantiated on multiple pages open at the same time? The session value will only work for one of the pages/captcha images.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set it in the session and then when it's posted, you need to check with the value in the session

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You want to marshall that instance and save it in a session, since HTTP is stateless. You can then demarshall it on the second page.

**However**:

Most PHP captcha system I've seen do not need this functionality, rather the check function should work independently and usually compares the data from a stored session and a POST variable.

Answer (score 1):

What is the handler mapping needed in IIS 7.x to produce CAPTCHA images? The only one that works seems to be the wildcard, which is ridiculous from a security point of view. In tightening the security of ColdFusion according to the lock-down guide at http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/whitepapers/pdf/91025512_cf9_ lockdownguide_wp_ue.pdf, they recommend to remove this wildcard mapping, but that seems to break [CAPTCHA](http://www.gather.com/viewArticle.action?articleId=281474979564764).